# LDAP Query not returning all queried attributes

Tags: c#, ldap, ldap-query

Is there any reason why a LDAP query does not return all attributes passed in the request?

My request looks like this:

```
// assembling the attribute list
var ldapAttributeList = FieldMappings.AdminDirMappings.Where(
fieldMapping => !fieldMapping.IsOUPath).Select(
fieldMapping => fieldMapping.ADFieldName).ToArray();

// build the query for the current user
var ldapSearchRequest = new SearchRequest(
configuration[LdapConnectivity.AdminDirRootDirectoryKey],
MakeAdminDirEmployeeNumberFilter(adminDirContact.EmployeeId),
SearchScope.Subtree, ldapAttributeList);
```

The property "attributeList" contains 25 fields I want to query from LDAP. The response returns only 16 attributes.

Is there a reason for that? Maybe if the LDAP fields are empty they are not returned or similar?

I have no clue why it returns only a subset of the needed fields.

any ideas or hints?

Comment: Using LDAP, if there are no values there is nothing returned.

Comment: Hi Paul - jwilleke actually answered this question with his comment.  Do you have any feedback for him?  Do you have any other concerns?

Comment: Hello all, hi jwilleke. Indeed the mentioned fact is correct. So the mistake wason the LDAP side. Thank you very much for the hint

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, and just maybe, you are using global catalog port 3269 instead of default port 636 for retrieving all atributtes.

Comment: More of a comment rather then an answer